# Audit.NET Entity Framework to audit one same entry to two tables

Tags: entity-framework, audit, audit.net

I Have 2  Audit tables one is Audit_ProfileFan and second is Audit_StatusChanges
The first table `AuditProfileFan`  should audit every time update or insert has been made to ProfileFan Table.
The second  Audit_StatusChanges should only audit when an update of a certain column FanStatusId is made.

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup() .UseEntityFramework(ef => ef.AuditTypeExplicitMapper(m => m
        .Map<FanActivity, Audit_FanActivity>((fanActivity, auditFanActivity) =>
        {
            auditFanActivity.ProfileFanId = fanActivity.ProfileFanId;
            auditFanActivity.ActivityId = auditFanActivity.ActivityId;

        })
        .Map<DeliveryActions, Audit_DeliveryActions>((deliveryAction, auditDeliveryAction) =>
        {
            auditDeliveryAction.ProfileFanId = deliveryAction.FanId;
            auditDeliveryAction.DeliveryActionId = deliveryAction.DeliveryActionId;
        })
        .Map<Fan, Audit_Fan>()
        .Map<ProfileFan, Audit_StatusChanges>((profileFan, auditStatusChanges) =>
        {
            auditStatusChanges.ProfileFanId = profileFan.Id;
            //auditStatusChanges.OriginalValue = profileFan.FanStatusId;
            //auditStatusChanges.NewValue = profileFan.FanStatusId;
        })
        .Map<ProfileFan, Audit_ProfileFan>((profileFan, auditProfileFan) =>
        {
            auditProfileFan.ProfileFanId = profileFan.Id;
            auditProfileFan.FanId = profileFan.FanId;
            auditProfileFan.EmailResponseStatusId = profileFan.EmailResponseStatusId;
            auditProfileFan.FanStatusId = profileFan.FanStatusId;
        })
        .Map<TagFan, Audit_TagFan>((tagFan, auditTagFan) =>
        {
            auditTagFan.ProfileFanId = tagFan.ProfileFanId;
            auditTagFan.TagId = tagFan.TagId;
        })
        .AuditEntityAction<IAuditLog>((evt, entry, auditEntity) =>
        {
            if(entry.Table=="ProfileFan" && entry.Action=="Update")
            {
                //auditEntity.OriginalValue = profileFan.FanStatusId;
                //auditEntity.NewValue = profileFan.FanStatusId;
            }

            auditEntity.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            auditEntity.AuditUser = evt.Environment.UserName;
            auditEntity.Action = entry.Action; // Insert, Update, Delete
            auditEntity.AuditUsername = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        })
    )
);
```

But every time an update is made it audits only one table in this case Audit_ProfileFan.

Is my requirement possible or should I do some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with the current version of the [EntityFramework data provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/Providers/EntityFrameworkDataProvider.cs), since you can only map from the known *entity type* and nothing else.

**But** I've found a way to allow that kind of use cases with minimal impact, by adding a new `Map<T>` overload that lets you specify the final audit type as a function of the [EventEntry](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/03a6e9dbffc7cccb9b9eb8cf184d709dcbc9f8fc/src/Audit.EntityFramework/EventEntry.cs#L8), so you would be able to map the same input data type to multiple output audit types, depending on the modified entry.

So for example you could map `ProfileFan` to different tables depending on the SQL operation (insert/update), with something like this:

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup() 
    .UseEntityFramework(ef => ef.AuditTypeExplicitMapper(m => m
        .Map<ProfileFan>(
            mapper: entry => entry.Action == "Insert" ? typeof(Audit_ProfileFan) : typeof(Audit_StatusChanges), 
            entityAction: (ev, entry, entity) =>
            {
                if (entity is Audit_ProfileFan pf)
                {
                    // action for profile fan
                    // pf.xxxx = ...;
                }
                else if (entity is Audit_StatusChanges ss)
                {
                    // action for status changes
                    // ss.xxxx = ...;
                }
            })
        .Map<TagFan, Audit_TagFan>(/*...*/)
        .AuditEntityAction<IAuditLog>((evt, entry, auditEntity) =>
        {
            // common action...
        })));
```

This will be released soon, [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/commit/bd80812fcd2d30e0107bdecdf9bb7652b18f779a) is the commit with the changes.

## UPDATE

This is included on `Audit.EntityFramework` library starting on version 14.6.2